# Forcing a module mock to throw an error in a test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a try/catch block in my functions that I want to test. Both functions call the same `execute` function and will catch if it throws an error. My tests are setup where I'm mocking the module near the top, and I can then verify how many times that jest function is called.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to *force* `execute` to throw an error on the second test, and then go back to the default mock implementation. I've tried re-assigning jest.mock in the individual test but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import {execute} from '../src/execute'

jest.mock('../src/execute', () => ({
  execute: jest.fn()
}))

describe('git', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    Object.assign(action, JSON.parse(originalAction))
  })

  describe('init', () => {
    it('should stash changes if preserve is true', async () => {
      Object.assign(action, {
        silent: false,
        accessToken: '123',
        branch: 'branch',
        folder: '.',
        preserve: true,
        isTest: true,
        pusher: {
          name: 'asd',
          email: 'as@cat'
        }
      })

      await init(action)
      expect(execute).toBeCalledTimes(7)
    })
  })

  describe('generateBranch', () => {
    it('should execute six commands', async () => {
       jest.mock('../src/execute', () => ({
         execute: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
           throw new Error('throwing here so. I can ensure the error parsed properly');
         });
      }))

      Object.assign(action, {
        silent: false,
        accessToken: '123',
        branch: 'branch',
        folder: '.',
        pusher: {
          name: 'asd',
          email: 'as@cat'
        }
      })
      
      // With how this is setup this should fail but its passing as execute is not throwing an error
      await generateBranch(action)
      expect(execute).toBeCalledTimes(6)
    })
  })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jest.mock` in `should execute six commands` doesn't affect `../src/execute` module because it has already been imported at top level.

`jest.mock` at top level already mocks `execute` with Jest spy. It's preferable to use `Once` implementation to not affect other tests:

```
it('should execute six commands', async () => {
     execute.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
       throw new Error('throwing here so. I can ensure the error parsed properly');
     });
     ...
```

Also the mock should be forced to be ES module because `execute` is named import:

```
jest.mock('../src/execute', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  execute: jest.fn()
}))
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. I had to reference it as `(execute as jest.mock).mockImplementationOnce(() =>)` otherwise it threw a type error.

Comment: The question doesn't mention you use Typescript. This one can help for proper types, https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md#mocked